# Both click and longclick respond in listview

Tags: java, android

I have implemented both onItemClickListener and onItemLongClickListener in my ListView.
- itemClick to start a new activity;
- itemLongClick to open a popup.
 But when I longpress an item both listeners react.

How do I set OnClick not to respond when I longpress?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true in LongClick then onClick will not be called. Look at this: [how to implement onItemLongClickListener and onItemClickListener event on listview row in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289794/how-to-implement-onitemlongclicklistener-and-onitemclicklistener-event-on-listvi)

This question has been answered previously on this forum. :)